# Prove that that $\exists c \in (0,3)$ such that $f''(c) =0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f: [0,3] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function function.

$f(0) = f(3) = 0 $ and $f'(0)f'(3)\geq0$

prove that that $\exists c \in (0,3)$ such that $f''(c) =0$

assume: $f'(0)>0$ and $f'(3)>0$ (the case where one is equal to zero is trivial)

Rolle's theorem: $\exists \hspace0.1cm \alpha \in(0,3) \hspace0.1cm f'(\alpha)=0$

lagrange's theorem:

$f'(3) - f'(\alpha) = f''(\beta)(3-\alpha)$ $\implies  f''(\beta) > 0$

$f'(\alpha) - f'(0) = f''(\beta)(\alpha)$   $\implies  f''(\beta) < 0$

but since the 2nd derivative is not necessary a continuous function I can't conclude $f''(\beta) = 0$

can this be fixed or am I missing something?

Comment: See [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), you can use the intermediate value theorem on derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By mean value theorem(MVT), $\exists a\in(0,3)$ such that $f'(a) = \frac{f(3) - f(0)}{3} = 0$.

Without loss of generality, $f'(0) > 0, f'(3) > 0$. Since $f\in C^1$, $\exists b\in (0, a), d\in(a,3)$ such that $f'(b) = f'(d) = {1\over2}\min\{f'(0), f'(3)\}$.

Applying MVT on $(b, d)$ gives a point $c\in(b, d)$ with $f''(c) = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f'(0)>0,f'(3)>0$. By the continuity of $f'(x)$ at $x=0,3$, there are $a,b\in(0,3), a<b$ such that
$$ f(a)=f(0)+f'(c_1)a>0,f(b)=f(3)+f'(c_2)(x-3)<0 $$
for some $c_1\in(0,a),c_2\in(b,3)$. By IMVT, there is $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0$. Now applying the Rolle's theorem in $[0,c]$ and $[c,3]$, there is $d_1\in(0,c),d_2\in(c,3)$ such that
$$ f'(d_1)=f'(d_2)=0. $$
Applying Rolle's theorem in $[d_1,d_2]$, one concludes that there is $d\in(d_1,d_2)\subset(0,3)$ such that $f''(d)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG  $f'(0)>0$ and $f'(3)>0.$ As $f(0)=f(3)$ there is $0<c<3$ such that $f'(c)=0.$ Hence  the minimal value of  $f'$ is attained at some point $0<d<3.$ Thus $f''(d)=0.$